# insert/create interactive scheme inside windows form

Tags: c, windows-forms-designer

I am currently trying to create a schematics for a local electrical circuit inside a town that has both rural and urban electrical paths, both being powered by the station throughout the 20 kV. The problem is that i need to insert this schematic inside a Windows form as it is, but drawn on PC, the task is that once I have this schematics from black all the electrical lines will switch to green to show the working state and once clicked a TP it will turn red for all the other TP that are not connected in any other way.

I am not really sure how to do this, the only solutions I could think of was either use toolbox items and just try to make the scheme but it would be hard and look creepy, or just try to make more drawings in autocad and just change the color one by on for each case and make the photo change based to the button (hidden over TP) but it wouldn't be practical if more than 1 TP would crash.

Do you have any better idea of doing this?

Here you have the schematic that I have the create and the second is an example as how it should actually work:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you use SVG or some kind of vector drawing library that does symbols?

Comment: i found a temporary solution , by just creating and shaping buttons as TP and CL but I'm not sure how to work with the powerlines , if i can draw them inside the form and just command the color change or if i have to use still the toolbox items to get past this , im not faimiliar with drawing library or anything alike

Comment: Windows Form Designer is a really simple tool. For anything non-trivial you really need to draw the stuff yourself in custom controls. If you're stuck using just C you can do this with the Windows GDI, but you may find C++ approaches give you way more tools.